# Burger Button Menu Not Appearing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm new to Vue and Nuxtjs, but I'm trying to make a menu bar across the top of the screen that disappears and is replaced with a "burger" button when the tab is small and the menu doesn't fits across the screen.

I have achieved this so far, my only issue is that when I click the "burger" button, the menu items don't show up. How do I achieve this?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-between h-16">
        <div class="flex items-center">
          <div class="hidden md:block">
            <div class="ml-10 flex items-baseline">
              <a
                href="/product"
                class="font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
                >Product
              </a>
              <a
                href="/linkone"
                class="ml-10 font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
                >Title One
              </a>
              <a
                href="/linktwo"
                class="ml-10 font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
                >Title Two
              </a>
              <!--              <a-->
              <!--                href="/pricing"-->
              <!--                class="ml-10 font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"-->
              <!--                >Pricing-->
              <!--              </a>-->
              <a
                href="/about"
                class="ml-10 font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
                >About
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="-mr-2 flex md:hidden">
          <!-- Mobile menu button -->
          <button
            type="button"
            class="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-500 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
            id="main-menu"
            aria-label="Main menu"
            aria-haspopup="true"
          >
            <!-- Menu open: "hidden", Menu closed: "block" -->
            <svg
              class="block h-6 w-6"
              stroke="currentColor"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            >
              <path
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
                stroke-width="2"
                d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"
              />
            </svg>
            <!-- Menu open: "block", Menu closed: "hidden" -->
            <svg
              class="hidden h-6 w-6"
              stroke="currentColor"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            >
              <path
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
                stroke-width="2"
                d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"
              />
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--
      Mobile menu, toggle classes based on menu state.

      Open: "block", closed: "hidden"
    -->
    <div class="hidden md:hidden">
      <div class="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 sm:px-3">
        <a
          href="#"
          class="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-white bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700"
          >Product</a
        >
        <a
          href="#"
          class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700"
          >Title One</a
        >
        <a
          href="#"
          class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700"
          >Title Two</a
        >
        <a
          href="#"
          class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700"
          >About</a
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Which css framework you uses?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through a state variable in data and binding classes to elements dynamically

```
// component
data() {
   return {
     isOpen: false
   }
}

<!-- template -->
<button @click="isOpen = !isOpen">Toggle</button>
<div 
  class="menu"
  :class="{hidden: !isOpen}"
>
  ...
</div>
```

The hidden class is set, if the condition (set as object value) is true.